# GAE initialization recommended practice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, initialization

I've a Java GAE app that should clear the memcache whenever I deploy a new version of the app.   I'm using static initializer, i.e.
    static {
        MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService().clearAll();
    }

However, that would clear the memcache as well whenever a new instance is started, which is not desired behavior.

What is the proper way to execute initialization code?

TIA

Comment: Why not just version your memcache entries and discard them if the version doesn't match, rather than trying to programmatically clear the entire contents of memcache with each deploy? If you include the version number in the memcache key, it will effectively take care of this for you (because if foo-1-blah is in cache and you try to request foo-2-blah, that will be a miss).

Comment: There's no way to run something just once on each deploy, unless you run it yourself when deploying. Amber's suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

I create my memcache keys using a factory and they always get appended with the version number of my app so when i upload a new version, the keys are new I forget about the old cached values, which will go away on their own.

I also have a servlet defined in web.xml with a security constraint for admin only, then I browse to it's URL (/admin/example) manually after an upgrade - logging in as as admin. The servlet has my run once code in it to kick off any tasks for upgrading store data and purging the cache.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Update: Google recently added a button to the admin console for purging the memcache on your app. So whenever i upgrade, now i just hit that button.

Answer (score -4):

One time initializations of applications can be done in the init() method of the Servlet.  Here is an example

```
public class CatalogServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private BookDB bookDB;
   public void init() throws ServletException {
      bookDB = (BookDB)getServletContext().
         getAttribute("bookDB");
}
```

In the above example, the ServletContext attribute is, of course, just a variable that exists between servlet calls (the normal way to maintain state).  This, of course, assumes that you somewhere else stored this variable in the ServletContext.  The other way is to create the variable in the deployment descriptor.

To set initialization parameters within your deployment descriptor (web.xml), here is an example:

```
<servlet
    <servlet-name...
    <servlet-class ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>param1</param-name>
        <param-value>value1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

If this doesn't answer it, please clarify "whenever a new instance is started".

Comment: The init method would be called each time an instance is started by App Engine, which can happen any time due to request load or inactivity. So it is incorrect to assume the init method would be called ONLY after deploy, which was what the poster requested.

Comment: He's not asking for how to obtain initialisation parameters, he's asking how you run initialisation code only once per deploy.  Given that GAE will spin up and rip down instances willy-nilly, with potentially hundreds of instances running at once, it's a good question.